# How to scroll the background slower than the content?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, themes, drupal-8

I'm on "Drupal 8" and "Bootstrap 3".

How to scroll the background slower than the content ?

Here is an example :

http://komante.com/articles/smooth_background_image_scrolling

And here is my site :

https://www.s1biose.com

Comment: The term you are looking for is "parallax". Here is a bit about it https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: @ihpar Thanks but on your link the background is fixed and I want it to scroll slower than the content.

Comment: the link was just for a starting point. In this video series you can find how to accomplish multiple types and ways of parallax effect. Hope it helps https://youtu.be/STwoa-9jxi0

Comment: @ihpar perfect. Thank you

Comment: glad it helped.